# Picasso Load image from filesystem

Tags: android, picasso

Can I use Picasso library to load images from the filesystem?

I'm using `startActivityForResult` to let the user pick a photo from his gallery, and then want to show the selected image.

I already have working code to get the image filesystem `Uri`, but can't get the `Picasso.load()` method to work.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Of course you can. Its actually pretty straight forward:

```
File f = new File("path-to-file/file.png");
```

or

```
File f = new File(uri);

Picasso.get().load(f).into(imageView);
```

also

```
Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageView);
```

works

Comment: I don't know if it's a "specific" URI format that Picasso requires to load the images from the filesystem (in String format). But I used the one returned from ActivityResult and it didn't work until I passed a File object, instead of the String directly.

Comment: I am trying to do that but this is not working, i got a File from another activity to my app cache but Picasso dont load it...

Comment: patrickf's answer does the trick, however since Picasso has changed a little since the answer was posted, you'll need to use the following syntax:

`Picasso.get().load(f).into(imageView);`

or

`Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageView);`

or

`Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

Answer (score 30):

Yes you can.

Try:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(YOUR_FILE_PATH)).into(imageView);
```

**EDIT**

You can also call `.load(YOUR_URI)` instead as well.

Answer (score 25):

Looking in the source code I also discover that you can load the image from filesystem adding `file:` string prefix to your image path. For example:

```
file:path/to/your/image
```

Also, when using startActivityForResult, you will get something like this:

```
Uri imageContent = data.getData();
```

Then, you can call `Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageContent.toString).into(imageView);` directly without need to create a `Cursor` and querying for the image path.

Comment: Thank you, mine didn't work until I saw your answer that the "file:" prefix is needed.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. There is my path - "file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.fittingroom.newtimezone/files/default/AvatarPackage/DEFAULT_MY_AVATAR/pose1.jpeg" , but any result (

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko it should start with `file://`. Your Uri is missing the second `/`.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("file://"+path) // Add this
.config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.fit().centerCrop()
.into(imageView);
```

It work perfect for me.

Comment: mh, I would use RGB_8888 unless you have issues with memory constraints due to the image being really big

Answer (score 7):

```
> Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
> Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
> Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

Comment: This is the way to do it with new versions of Picasso. `Picasso.with()` is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Basically we need three things, `Context`, `image´s path` and the `ImageView` Container

**Old version of Picasso**:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load("/files/my_image.jpg").into(myImageView);
```

**Newer version of Picasso**:

```
 Picasso.get().load("/files/my_image.jpg").into(myImageView);
```

but we can make use of more options:

```
  .resize(20, 20)
  .centerCrop()
  .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
  .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
```

etc...

more info : **http://square.github.io/picasso/**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone trying to do this with Kotlin then here it is...

//variables

```
private lateinit var addImage: ImageView  // set the id of your ImageView
private lateinit var imageUri: Uri
```

//open gallery to select an image

```
val gallery = Intent()
        gallery.type = "image/*"
        gallery.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select picture"), PICK_IMAGE)
```

//next

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageUri = data?.data!!
            try {

                Picasso.get()
                    .load(imageUri)
                    .into(addImage)

            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

That's all you need.