# Images in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView in Android and I am having some trouble with images.

I would like to display a list of the images in a particular folder with their path names.

So this is my `row.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="test" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my adapter, I use this code to set the image of a row:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    holder.mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://" + mMediaStorageDir.getPath() + "/" + mDataset[position]));
}
```

The images load fine, but when I scroll down the whole app becomes very slow.

This doesn't happen when I load a small drawable instead. Is it because the pictures are too big?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. I think it's too big.

You need load firstly your images(track for free memory) and after that use him.

Not necessarily use Picasso. **But you can use it.**

I recommend to you read the

- [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
- [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)
- [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

And example :

**ItemData.java**

```
package com.shustikov.android;

public class ItemData {

    private String title;
    private int imageUrl;

    public ItemData(String title,int imageUrl){

        this.title = title;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getImageUrl() {
       return imageUrl;
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewExampleAdapter.java**

```
package com.shustikov.android;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecyclerViewExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewExampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ItemData[] itemsData;

    public RecyclerViewExampleAdapter(ItemData[] itemsData) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewExampleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                               .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
        viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());
     }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtViewTitle;
        public ImageView imgViewIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't really see how this makes big images load faster.

Comment: @Gejii Everything has been thought up for you. Read provided links and choose your improvement way.

Comment: I am trying this code. How to set imageUrl as integer?

Comment: @Atul imageUrl - is `Integer` O_O

Comment: I got URL of image (e.g. http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png)

Comment: @Atul Image view doesn't support loading images from URL. In your case you need setup placeholder and load images separately. In your case Picasso can helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You're loading your images on UI thread, that's the problem. Loading file from disk or network takes some time. You can achieve the same, but using Picasso library. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681177/picasso-load-image-from-filesystem).

Comment: @Gejii then please post your logcat output.

Comment: Anyone who is still looking for memory problem, here is the link: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library

Answer (score 1):

It takes time to mold the code using caching method and loading images before the fragment is displayed. An easy approach would be to use the Picasso Library. I myself used Picasso and now images load quite fast as I scroll.

Here is my code:

```
public void bindPhoto(Photo photo) {
    mPhoto = photo;
    mPhotoFile=PhotoLab.get(getActivity()).getPhotoFile(mPhoto);
    Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(mPhotoFile);

    if(mPhotoFile==null || !mPhotoFile.exists()){
        int imgdrawable=R.drawable.ic_action_name3;
        mThumbnail.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imgdrawable));
    } else {
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(uri).fit().into(mThumbnail);
    }


    mTitleTextView.setText(mPhoto.getTitle());
    String dateFormat = "EEE, MMM dd";
    dateString = DateFormat.format(dateFormat, mPhoto.getDate()).toString();
    mDateTextView.setText(dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of Data containing the image Uri's in your main Activity (Where your adapter is called) such as in **MainActivity.java**

```
contacts.add(new Data(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Usama Zafar" , 400));
```

.
.
.

then in your Adapter (**MainAdapter.java**)

inside the onBindViewHolder() method you can write as

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int 
position) {

    final Data currentItem =ls.get(position);
    
    holder.img.setImageDrawable(c.getDrawable(currentItem.getImage()));
    holder.name.setText(currentItem.getName());
    holder.amount.setText(currentItem.getAmount());
}
```