# select multiple images and insert into multiple different imageViews

Tags: java, android

I would like to select multiple images and display these images into different separate ImageViews. I select a multiple images, but it shows the same image view. Please help I'm really stuck.

For Example. if the user selects 2 pic direct set into imageview 1 and imageview 2

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_BROWSE_PICTURE);

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_BROWSE_PICTURE){
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    ivImage1.setImageURI(null);
                    ivImage1.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**First try to get all images** `data.getClipData` - check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023265/9427138)

store this to an arraylist for Recyclerview

**Show selected image**

create multiple image views instead of single one. `ivImage1, ivImage2` etc or use [Images in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26890631/9427138)

Answer (score 0):

Get all Uris:

```
ClipData clip = data.getClipData();

for(int i = 0; i < clip.getItemCount(); i++) {
    ClipData.Item item = clip.getItemAt(i);
    Uri uri = item.getUri();
    urilist.add(uri);
}
```

Then pass the urilist to a listView or recyclerView adapter.