# problems with images in recyclerview using picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am downloading an image from internet and this is the path I chose to save it on the phone:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(mContext);
File directory = cw.getDir("imagesDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory,"profile.jpg"));
```

After the image has been downloaded I'm using this to get the path:

```
String databasePath = mContext.getDir("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
databasePath = databasePath + "imagesDB/profile.jpg";
```

And then in my recyclerview adapter I use this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(databasePath).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.Photo);
```

I always get the ic_launcher image displayed instead of the one I downloaded.

Am i using a wrong path for the image?

This is the code I use to download the image:

```
 URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.0.100/app/image/image1.jpg");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = url.openStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(mContext);
        File directory = cw.getDir("imagesDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory,"profile.jpg"));

        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            String databasePath = mContext.getDir("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
            Log.i("","Path1: "+ databasePath.toString());
            databasePath = databasePath + "imagesDB/profile.jpg";
            Log.i("","Path2: "+ databasePath.toString());
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First print _databasePath_ in Log and check its value.

Comment: I think image takes time from server to download and save. and you are attaching image using picaso before download it.

Comment: Have you given read write permission in your manifest? Also check that you get proper path in your variable

Comment: Try using AsyncTask, download image in doInBackground() and use picasso in onPostExecute()

Comment: please provide the image url  for same

Comment: @Piyush In my program i printed the path

Comment: @Piyush In my program i printed the path. It looks like this "/data/user/0/org.geo.httpwww/app_" where "org.geo.httpwww" is my package name

Comment: @GrIsHu yes i added the permission and the image gets downloaded on the phone, I think I'm getting problems trying to find the path

Comment: @Mohit Trived I updated the question, pls help

Comment: @Bansal Yes it takes time but now I have the image downloaded on the phone and it should work. I'm guessing is the path I¡m using inside the .load() is there another way to get the path image, besides the one I'm using, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that I can't pass a String to .load(), instead i have to create a new file like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(databasePath)).into(holder.artistPhoto);
```

By the way I found the solution in this post:
[Picasso Load image from filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681177/picasso-load-image-from-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Recycler Adapter Using Picasso. Rest of the code if any one needs ask for it I will upload.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<DogInfo> mArrayListInfo;
        private Context context;

            public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<DogInfo> mArrayListInfo,Context context) {
                this.mArrayListInfo = mArrayListInfo;
                this.context=context;
            }

            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lay_display,null);

                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                DogInfo dogInfo=mArrayListInfo.get(position);
                holder.mTextView.setText(dogInfo.getmInfo());

                Picasso.with(context).load(dogInfo.getmImage()).into(holder.mImageView);

            }



            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mArrayListInfo.size();
            }

            public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                ImageView mImageView;
                TextView mTextView;
                public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);


                    mImageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgShow);
                    mTextView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtShow);

                }
            }
        }
```