# Android - Sharing image url + Text using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, sharing

I need to share, an **external image url** together with text, 
from a WebView but for some reason I get errors on each Picasso override:

Already implemented the Javascript interface in Android.

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void shareContent(String text, String imageURL){
        shareData(text, imageURL);
    }
```

**Error I get:** `Method does not override method from its superclass`.

```
public void shareData(String url) {
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(new AppLink.Target() {
        @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("image/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(bitmap));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));
        }
        @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
        @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
    });
}
```

And the method to get the local saved image

```
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681177/picasso-load-image-from-filesystem

Comment: I am. You're reading a file from disk, then calling a share intent. Not sure why Picasso is even needed here

Comment: For performance.

Comment: I don't see an external image url... I think you may be confusing `getExternalFilesDir` with something else?

Comment: When clicking on "share" within the Webview; I'm receiving an image url  and the associated text that needs to be share using the share intent

Comment: Java!=Javascript... What interface?

Comment: Can you please show your WebView related code so your question is a [mcve]?

Comment: You know that I guess: @JavascriptInterface
  public void shareContent(String text, String imageURL){
   shareData(text, imageURL);
  } (to communicate between js and java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you tried to implement the methods of Picasso, but you're actually doing it for the Applink.Target

```
into(new AppLink.Target() {
```

I think you're looking for this

```
into(new com.squareup.picasso.Target() {
```

Comment: Just found out as well, thanks mate :) - The import was wrong, after imported from Picasso, I only have: new Target()