# How to customzie my RecyclerView Adapter to show the ImageView directly for the sender?

Tags: android, firebase, android-imageview, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android/Firebase chat app that send images.
After a gallery intent, I get the Uri in onActivityResult and assign it to a public Uri in the activity.
My question is that how can I customize the RecyclerView adapter to show the image directly for the sender only without the need to wait the image to be uploaded to Firebase then retrieving it?

Comment: i think besides firebase you may use websockets to send data database and retrieve at receiving end..this is what i understood by your model

Comment: I thought it could be simply taking the Uri and set it with Picasso to the ImageView in the adapter but it does not show

Comment: try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681177/picasso-load-image-from-filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in the sender bind in your adapter to set the image with Picasso and with if statement: `if(theUri != null)`