# The transparent image is transparent somewhere in the application and is not transparent somewhere else

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, transparency

In an Android application,
I have a transparent png image which is truly transparent under the following conditions:

```
final ImageView btnsB = new ImageView(this);
;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
paramsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.layout1);

btnsB.setLayoutParams(paramsB);
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.a11).resize(B_w, B_h).into(btnsB);

my_layout.addView(btnsB);
```

But when I try to use the same image somewhere else it is not transparent and the parts of the image which are supposed to be transparent are black and this is the problematic conditions (***Row_2_ll_img*** below is the mentioned image):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Row_1_txt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_colors"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/color00"
            android:layout_marginRight="5mm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5mm"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.1mm"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.1mm"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Row_2_ll"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Row_2_ll_txt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border_colors"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/color00"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Row_2_ll_img"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/Row_2_ll_view"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The point is the above xml is a view which is used in a RecyclerView's item

More information:

I use interface to receive the click event from RecyclerView's item and then open the Galley and select the mentioned image and then receive the URI of the image and then :

```
        View v = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(10);
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.Row_2_ll_img);
        Picasso.with(this).load(Uri_M4_ViewPager_MagnifierIcon).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).resize(Dimension_x_6mm, Dimension_x_6mm).into(mImageView);
```

Image:
[image]

Edit: Glide and Picasso has the same problem.

Comment: How are you setting the image in your ImageView `Row_2_ll_img`?

Comment: I added more information above

Comment: @AndroidVH1001 can you show both screens preview here?

Comment: I added the image (the black part is the problem and in the true condition it is not exhibited)

Comment: It might be a problem with Picasso. Try loading the image directly through `mImageView.setImageURI(Uri_M4_ViewPager_MagnifierIcon)`. Or use Glide instead

Comment: Ohhh, yes it is ok now, but why? how can I use Picasso instead? is anything I have to set for Picasso?

Comment: Glide has the same problem too!

Comment: Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681177/picasso-load-image-from-filesystem

Comment: The problem still persists