# How can I save an Image to the phone of the user ? and later load it?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, fileoutputstream

I have followed a lot of guides of how to save and reload images to the phone and came to this:
In the videos it works but for some reason it does not work for me.

Is there maybe a better version of doing this? And how can I read from this later so I can paste it with Picasso into another ImageView?

(Update: Logcat is saying : Logcat says this: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LiFit/profileimage.jpg (No such file or directory) but I am clearly creating this folder wiht the mkdir command so why isn´t it workiing ?)

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) profilBild.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/LiFit");
directory.mkdir();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(directory, fileName);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pic saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    try {
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(outFile));
        getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you ask for write permissions? Are there some error messages in the [logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this/23353174#23353174)?

Comment: Have you given the permissions to give access storage of the device?

Comment: and about the picasso question, there is no problem with loading [local images with picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681177/picasso-load-image-from-filesystem)

Comment: Logcat says this:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LiFit/profileimage.jpg (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you need to change the permissions in the app settings to....